# Android get user gender from Google account

Tags: android, gmail

Is there a way to get the user gender from the used Gmail account on the device?
If yes, how?
If not, is there any other way t get the user gender automatically, without asking them?

Comment: If you are integrating Gplus Login in your app. You can get google plus profile... then your get gender too by this method currentPerson.getGender();

Comment: what if I dont have any specific logins connected to my app?

Comment: then You cant get it.. BTW whose gender you wanna get if u dont have anybody there???

Comment: I was thinking about getting the gender from the Gmail account associated with the ANdroid device (you know, if the user has entered that info in their google profile)

Comment: first u need to write code to get gmail account associated with device... then Use person profile using GPlus, and getgender.